# How to detect which breaker has tripped?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-breaker

I want to test how long it takes for four breakers in series to trip. I want to be able to identify which breaker first tripped.

I came up with this circuit. S1 to S4 are the breakers. Only S1 is pulsed (to simulate a trip). The differential circuit is the "detection" circuit. Hence it will be placed in parallel across all four breakers. I just have it across S1 for simulation.

[image]

When the breaker trips I accepted a binary output. However I get this on the output:

[image]

This is clearly not a binary output I can feed into a micro.

Is there a circuit that I can use that can give me two clear DC voltages for when the breaker is tripped and when it is not tripped?

Comment: What is the voltage across R7? Is it enough to operate an optoisolator LED?

Comment: @AndrewMorton R7 is used to set the current for the breakers.

Comment: What do you mean which one "first" tripped? Only one of them will ever trip.

Comment: @Hearth but not all the breakers are exactly the same (even though they can be all 10A). S2 can trip first. Breakers have a min and max time to trip. Hence one can trip before the other. S2 may by the one that has the quickest trip time, and S4 may the longest trip time.

Comment: @JoeyB Yes, but once the first breaker trips, the current stops, so none of the others will trip.

Comment: @Hearth but even once a breaker "decides" to trip it still takes a finite amount of time to actually trip - time in which another breaker might also "decide" to trip. End result being 2 tripped breakers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Below is the final circuit, the signal it first feeds into a differential op-amp

[image]

The output of U1 looks like this:
[image]

I then used a peak hold detector to convert this sine wave to a DC equivalent signal. The output of this looks like this:
[image]

Finally, the signal is fed into a comparator circuit. The output looks like this:
[image]

This was then fed into the opto and we got a nice clean binary output.
[image]

The delay is due to the peak hold circuit, which can be fine-tuned for the application.

Answer (score 1):

I would never connect an MCU to a mains circuit. I would isolate with an opto-isolated transistor.

This simulator doesn't have an optocoupler. But you can see the output by looking at the current in D5. C1 isn't necessary if you are only looking for the rising edge.

You probably wouldn't want to waste this much power in R2 if this was a permanent circuit, but this is fine for a one-time test. R2 should be at least a 1 Watt resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYnVte.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Plot of the current through D5 and the power in R2.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a binary output, hence the down vote. I have added my answer to what I needed.

Comment: @JoeyB - I did the hard part, I assumed that you had enough experience to add a comparator.